# Having trouble changing URL from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, rails-routing

Right now when I click on a country I get `country/(country_id)`
example ...`country/1`

However when I click on a state I get

`country/1?city=5958`

I would like to see `country/1/city/1`

Comment: Can we see your routes.rb file?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Perhaps add some code, gems used, etc.

Comment: That looks like a mashup of rails and php params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some nested routes in your `routes.rb`... and for convention over configuration you should use plurals.

```
resources :countries do
  resources :cities
end
```

And then when you "click on a state" for show, the link should be something like...

```
link_to country_city_path(my_country, my_city)
```

... of course, replacing your own variable names.

This will create a url of `countries/1/cities/1` which will call the `show` action in `CitiesController`

Answer (score 1):

Try routes nesting like below in routes file

```
resources :countries do
  resources :cities
end
```